# Duplicate a line the same number of times as column 1

Tags: linux, bash, shell

There are several questions about how to duplicate lines, I want to automatically duplicate each line the specific number of times as found in field one of a file. I have a large file with two fields, field one is a number, field two is the information in question, like this.

```
12     AAA
18     BBB
25     CCC
33     DDD
```

I would to duplicate each line so it is represented the same number of times as the number in field one. So, I want 12 lines that say "12     AAA" and so on.

I know that I can manually paste each line x number of times in vim (copy and then "12p") but this seems onerous for a large file. Does anyone know a script that can do it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` same as JigglyNaga's answer:

```
awk '{ c=0; while ($1>c++) print }' infile
```

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
{ 
    for (c=strtonum($1) ; c ; c--) 
        print
}
```

Comment: A simple `$1+0` should also force the integer conversion right?

Comment: @Inian Provided the number is in decimal, it seems it doesn't even need the `+0`.  If the number is in eg. hex, `$1+0` gives no repeats, and `$1` gives infinite.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative awk solution:

```
<infile awk ' i=$1 { while(i--) print }'
```